# Does all NSURLConnections connect asynchronously? iOs

Tags: asynchronous, nsurlconnection

I've looked through some NSURLConnection examples, and all are titled as related asynchronously, although I didn't see any operation queue / thread/ dispatch created.
I was wondeirng - does NSURLConnection always preform requests asynchronously or you have to set something special for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSURLConnection can be run in synchronous or asynchronous mode depending on what method you call to make the actual connection once you've allocated the NSURLConnection Instance (or use the Class Methods).

For synchronous Connections, you use the method:

`+ (NSData *)sendSynchronousRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request returningResponse:(NSURLResponse **)response error:(NSError **)error`

For asynchronous connections, you use the methods:

`+ (NSURLConnection *)connectionWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request delegate:(id < NSURLConnectionDelegate >)delegate`

`- (id)initWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request delegate:(id < NSURLConnectionDelegate >)delegate`

`- (id)initWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request delegate:(id < NSURLConnectionDelegate >)delegate startImmediately:(BOOL)startImmediately`

`- (void)start`

I recommend reading Apple's Documentation on [NSURLConnection](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to find out more information and looking at sample code

Comment: Thank you for you quick reply :)
I have read the NSURLConnection reference & guide, yet I found it very unclear as the code isn't full.
another question - When using asynchronous connections, I should run on the main run loop until I recieve the DidFinishLoading message, right?

Comment: You can start the connection on the main run loop because the actual connection will be done in a new thread. When the connection is finished it will call your delegate methods if you've set your class as the delegate

Comment: I see.
is there any version of sendAsynchronousRequest available in iOs? cause I've only seen it on the mac os x reference, not ios.

In addition - I tried just creating a connection and waiting for it to call the messages, but for some reason they were'nt sent. when I made the code run on the current run loop until it was done, the messages got sent. this problem is weird, since I thought the delegate gets retained by the connection and therefor should not get released ( if that is indeed the case ) before the connection is finished/canceled/fails.

Comment: You are correct, iOS doesn't have a sendAsynchronousRequest method. What you are asking probably deserves a new question but basically you need to allocate a new NSURLConnection, set the Delegate and start the request, Here is some sample code which may help: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SimpleURLConnections/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009245. If you are really struggling I recommend you check out ASIHTTPRequest for Asynchronous Connections because I've found it has some really awesome documentation.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I will check those out :)