# How to return data gotten from a web service in objective- c (iPhone)?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

This might be a dumb question. Sorry if it is.

But Im working on a project that consumes web services. I can connect to the web service and get the data I need fine.

I would like to have a method that returns this data obtained from the web service to the caller. The only problem is that the data is only obtained inside the ConnectionDidFinishLoading method, and I can't access this data from my method.

here is my code, that works fine:

```
- (NSData *) dataForMethod:(NSString *)webMethod withPostString:(NSString *)postString
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[SigameWebServiceAddress stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@%@", @"/", webMethod]];
    NSMutableURLRequest *req = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postString length]];

    [req addValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [req addValue:msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [req setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [req setHTTPBody: [postString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:req delegate:self];
    if (conn) 
    {
        webData = [NSMutableData data];
    }   

    // I WOULD LIKE TO RETURN WEBDATA TO THE CALLER HERE, BUT WEBDATA IS EMPTY NOW, THE  
    //connectionDidFinishLoading ONLY GETS CALLED WITH THE DATA I WANT AFTER THE COMPILER
    //IS DONE EXECUTING MY METHOD.
}

-(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *) connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *) response 
{
    [webData setLength: 0];
}

-(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *) connection didReceiveData:(NSData *) data 
{
    [webData appendData:data];
}

-(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *) connection didFailWithError:(NSError *) error 
{
    NSLog(@"FATAL ERROR");
}

-(void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *) connection 
{
    NSLog(@"DONE. Received Bytes: %d", [webData length]);

    NSString *theXML = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes: [webData mutableBytes] length:[webData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    //---shows the XML---
    NSLog(@"%@", theXML);  //NOW, THIS IS THE DATA I WANT. BUT HOW CAN I RETURN THIS TO 
                           //THE CALLER. I MEAN, THE CALLER THAT CALLED MY METHOD 
                           //+ (NSData *) dataForMethod: withPostString:
}
```

Any help here is appreciated!
Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are really *two* ways to go about this.

1. **Create a *delegate* interface**
2. **Use Blocks**

I would strongly advise against using the synchronous methods - unless you are/have created your own asynchronous framework around them (i.e. you are manually starting another thread and executing your synchronous request on that thread). In the long run you will realize you need the requests to be async, and you'll have to re-work everything such that they are.

To give a quick overview of the two options I gave:

### 1. Create a *delegate* interface

The idea here is to create a class which performs the request, and create a protocol the *caller* must implement. When the request is complete, you will invoke a specified method on the delegate with the data:

The protocol might look something like this:

```
@protocol RequestClassDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)requestCompleted:(ResponseClass *)data;
- (void)requestError:(NSError *)error;

@end
```

The class which makes the request might look something like this:

```
@interface RequestClass : NSObject

- (void)makeRequest:(id<RequestClassDelegate>)delegate;

@end
```

And the request class implementation might contain some of the following, in addition to your connection logic:

```
@implementation RequestClass
{
    __weak id<RequestClassDelegate> _delegate;
}

// Connection Logic, etc.

- (void)makeRequest:(id<RequestClassDelegate>)delegate
{
    _delegate = delegate;
    // Initiate the request...
}

-(void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *) connection 
{
    NSString *theXML = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes: [webData mutableBytes] length:[webData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    // Processing, etc.

    // Here we'll call the delegate with the result:
    [_delegate requestCompleted:theResult];
}

@end
```

### 2. Use Blocks

This solution is much the same as the first solution - but, a bit more elegant in my opinion. Here, we'll change the `RequestClass` to use blocks instead of a delegate:

```
typedef void (^requestCompletedBlock)(id);
typedef void (^requestErrorBlock)(NSError *);
@interface RequestClass : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, copy) requestCompletedBlock completed;
@property (nonatomic, copy) requestErrorBlock errored;

- (void)makeRequest:(requestCompletedBlock)completed error:(requestErrorBlock)error;

@end
```

And the implementation of that might look something like this:

```
@implementation RequestClass

@synthesize completed = _completed;
@synthesize errored = _errored;

// Connection Logic, etc.

- (void)makeRequest:(requestCompletedBlock)completed error:(requestErrorBlock)error
{
    self.completed = completed;
    self.errored = error;
    // Initiate the request...
}

-(void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *) connection 
{
    NSString *theXML = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes: [webData mutableBytes] length:[webData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    // Processing, etc.

    // Here we'll call the delegate with the result:
    self.completed(theResult);
}

@end
```

Comment: thank you very much for pointing me in the right direction. Im new to iPhone programming and I have a bit of a hard time understanding the concepts of delegates, but the examples provided here really helped me understand it a little better. I'll keep working on it and let you guys know how it worked out for me. Once again thanks for the help!

Comment: Thanks you for such a thorough explanation. It was very helpful. :)

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are trying to use return the data synchronously from your method, but you are using an asynchronous method (using an NSURLConnection and presumably calling its start method) to begin retrieving data. If you really want your method to return its result synchronously, read on. As @Steve says in another answer, however, you may also reconsider your interface design and instead implement it using an asynchronous approach and use his recommendations for either a delegate or block-based interface.

If you want to return the data synchronously from your method, use a synchronous request. So change this part of your code:

```
conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:req delegate:self];
[conn start]; // I presume you have this somewhere
if (conn) 
{
    webData = [NSMutableData data];
}
```

with something more like this:

```
 NSURLResponse *response = nil;
 NSError *error = nil;
 webdata = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:req returningResponse:&response error:&error];
 if (webdata) {
     return webdata;
 }
 else {
     // Handle error by looking at response and/or error values
     return nil;
 }
```

You will no longer need any of your delegate code if you use this approach.  You will be limited in some ways though. For example, if your web service requires authentication via something other than URL parameters you can't use this approach.

Comment: Running this on the main thread will lead to freezing the UI. In many cases it's not unusual for connections to take several seconds to complete (meaning the UI is frozen for several seconds). Even if your code on the server doesn't take several seconds to complete - network lag, network bandwidth, and other factors can come into play which will create a several second lag. I'd highly advice NOT using the synchronous methods unless you already know for sure that your method won't be run on the UI thread.

Comment: @Steve - I agree 100%. I was trying to answer the question as it was asked rather than suggesting a completely different approach. You are correct that a synchronous interface has downsides and freezing the UI is a big one. I have edited my answer to reference yours as a good example of how a better interface design might be warranted for this class.

Comment: @TimDean, thank you very much for pointing me in the right direction. Im new to iPhone programming and I have a bit of a hard time understanding the concepts of delegates, but the examples provided here really helped me understand it a little better. I'll keep working on it and let you guys know how it worked out for me. Once again thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Steve's answer is great and I can only suggest the way using blocks. Actually, as I am new into Objective-C I implemented the approach steve outlined. It works perfectly.

The Post for more details and my own point of view you can find here:
http://kerkermeister.net/how-to-build-an-cocos2d-ios-app-communicating-with-a-restful-api-the-sequence/

The Post contains all the tiny steps you need to follow to get Steve's solution approach with blocks working. That includes:
- an updateable view that will render information as soon as retrieved from Web API asynchronously
- a controller invoking the HTTP request to the Web API
- the actual HttpRequest class that uses iOS standard NSURLConnections
- a model class that uses blocks as callbacks to update its data

Answer (score 0):

Your going to have to either implement a separate method in which you use the data once the data has been returned by the connectionDidFinishLoading method or make the request synchronously. The reason I believe the above does not work is because the request is happening on a separate thread, so the main thread continues, but does not actually have the data.

This is a good way to do that if synchronous is what you want:

[Does all NSURLConnections connect asynchronously? iOs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6806532/does-all-nsurlconnections-connect-asynchronously-ios)

Answer (score 0):

In order to download data from webserivce - use **NSURLSession** - 
*A URL session task that returns downloaded data directly to the app in memory.*

```
// 1. create NSURL link to your webservice
NSString *dataUrl = @"DATA_LINK_TO_WEBSERVICE";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:dataUrl];

// 2. create a NSURLSessionDataTask
NSURLSessionDataTask *downloadTask = [[NSURLSession sharedSession]
  dataTaskWithURL:url completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
  //Handle response here
}];

// 3.resume the task
[downloadTask resume];
```

Refernces:

1. apple documentation refrence:
   https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlsessiondatatask?language=objc
2. Raywanderlich great cookbook:
   https://www.raywenderlich.com/2392-cookbook-using-nsurlsession

Answer (score -1):

Your going to need to parse the XML that comes back. There are some good Objective C XML parsers out there. One in particular is made for ease of use....

http://nfarina.com/post/2843708636/a-lightweight-xml-parser-for-ios

It's a very light weight parser for extracting the values you want from XML. I've used many times with great success and little hassle. Here is how I query a web address and turn it into data.

```
 NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://WEB_ADDRESS_FOR_XML];
    NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:query];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:URL];
```

Or with NSURLConnection, in the did receive data:

```
-(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *) connection didReceiveData:(NSData *) data 
{
    //USE THE DATA RETURNED HERE....
}
```

Then use the Parser from my link to get the contents:

```
 SMXMLDocument *document = [SMXMLDocument documentWithData:data error:NULL];

    NSLog("\nXML Returned:%@",document);
```